# Twilio sms sending in Rails bugging AJAX success function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twilio

I am making a Rails application. My view sends an Ajax POST request to my server along with a phone number. I am using that phone number in the controller to call a model method that uses the Twilio API to send an sms to that number.

The problem is that even though the Twilio API sends successfully, the AJAX success function in my view is not run. What is causing the problem?

Here is the view:

```
<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('form').submit(function() {
      var phoneNumber = $(this).serialize();
      var submit = $(this).find(":submit");
      submit.attr("disabled", true);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
          data: phoneNumber,
          dataType: "JSON"
      }).success(function(json){
          console.log("success", json);
          submit.css("background-color", "green");
          submit.val("success");
      });
      return false; // prevents normal behaviour
      });
    });
  <% end %>
<% end %>


<%= form_tag(invite_with_twilio_reservation_path(@reservation, token: @reservation.token), method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:number, "Send to:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:number) %>
  <%= submit_tag("send")%>
<% end %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
  def invite_with_twilio
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    if params[:token] == @reservation.token
      authorize @reservation
    else
      raise
    end

    number = params[:number]
    status = @reservation.send_sms_invitation_to_number(number, current_user)

    if status == true
      render json: number, status: :ok
    else
      render json: number, status: :fail
    end
  end
```

And here is the model:

```
  def send_sms_invitation_to_number(number, user)
    club_name = tables.first.club.name
    account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_API_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_API_AUTH_TOKEN']

    Twilio.configure do |config|
      config.account_sid = account_sid
      config.auth_token = auth_token
    end

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new

    if @client.messages.create(
      from: "+13238005977" ,
      to: "#{number}",
      body: "Hey! Your buddy #{user.full_name}, wants to invite you to a reservation in #{club_name}, on the
      #{date}. Follow this link to accept his invitation and coordinate with your friends. #{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.reservation_url(self, token: self.token, host: 'localhost')}.")
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Again, the sms is sending successfully. The problem is the AJAX success function is not called and the button doesn't change neither text nor color.

Answer (score 0):

Try do to this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  data: phoneNumber,
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(json){
     // SMS success
  },
  error: function(json) {
    // SMS not sent
  }
});
```

I hope it helped you !

Comment: Thanks, Julien. Your suggestion helped me console.log the error, like this  error: function(json, err) {
    console.log(err)
  }

There seemed to be some parse error for some reason, when I was just passing in the number variable. When I tried, render json: @reservation, status: :ok. This time it worked. Honestly, I have no idea why it works now, but that's just another day of coding :D

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your problem here appears to be in your `$.ajax` function. Julien has suggested a way to fix it, but I thought I'd just go into what was wrong to help out. You code was:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
      data: phoneNumber,
      dataType: "JSON"
  }).success(function(json){
      console.log("success", json);
      submit.css("background-color", "green");
      submit.val("success");
  });
```

So you were calling `success` on the result of calling `$.ajax`. According to the jQuery documentation, `$.ajax` returns an object of type [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). This object used to respond to `success`, `error` and `complete` but they were deprecated and removed as part of jQuery 3.

Instead, you can either use the `success` key in the object of options you pass to `$.ajax` as Julien suggested. Or you can use the replacement for `success` which is `done`.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr('action'), //sumbits it to the given url of the form
      data: phoneNumber,
      dataType: "JSON"
  }).done(function(json){
      console.log("success", json);
      submit.css("background-color", "green");
      submit.val("success");
  });
```

Don't forget to implement `fail` as well so you can handle failures.

Comment: Thank you! You guys helped me a lot to locate the errors. There was also a parsing error for some reason.. I managed to fix it thanks to you guys.